# How do I get difference between two dates in android with millisec?

Tags: java, android

My SimpleDateFormat format is "HH:mm:ss.SSS"

My example time: "00:01:20.442"

How to get (extract) milliseconds **442** to string?

I found code:

```
long diff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
long mseconds = ?????????;
long seconds = diff / 1000;
long minutes = seconds / 60;
long hours = minutes / 60;
long days = hours / 24;
```

System.out.println("Milliseconds : "+ String.valueOf(mseconds));

P.S. I'm use API 19 (Adroid 4.4.2)

Comment: `long diffInMs = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();`

Comment: @Sam. - That's the OP's `diff` value.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You take the remainder of dividing by 1000, using the [remainder operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3):

```
long mseconds = diff % 1000;
```

But note that the milliseconds value you've asked for (442) doesn't match what you're doing to get `seconds`, `minutes`, etc. In `seconds`, you'll get the **total** number of seconds between the dates, which could be in the hundreds of thousands depending on the dates, not just 0-59.

**If** the goal is to get days, hours (within the day), minutes (within the hour), etc., then:

```
long mseconds = diff % 1000;
long seconds = (diff / 1000) % 60;
long minutes = (seconds / 60) % 60;
long hours = (minutes / 60) % 24;
long days = hours / 24;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Joda Time` library (which in my opinion should be in every project that uses time):

```
final long millis = DateTime.parse("00:01:20.442", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS")).getMillisOfSecond();
assertEquals(442, millis);
```

Or, if you want all of them:

```
final DateTime dt = DateTime.parse("00:01:20.442", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS"));

final long millis = dt.getMillisOfSecond(); //442
final long second = dt.getSecondOfMinute(); //20
final long min = dt.getMinuteOfHour(); //1
final long hour = dt.getHourOfDay(); //0
```

Comment: Yes, Joda library is recommended but only if it's API is used at many places. Just to do one operation, we should not add Joda library. Instead, we should use existing Java and Android APIs for it.

Comment: I disagree. If an app has a minimum SDK of less than 24, then I always use Joda if my app needs to do any work with dates or time. The library is so superior to `Calendar`, `DateFormat` and custom implementations that it's worthwhile even if it's only used once.

Comment: You didn't understood my point. I meant Joda library is heavy and 3rd party library so it is not recommended to use it in app where only 3-4 places date time objects are needed but for those in which there is lot of use of date time objects.

Comment: There are simpler solutions for that.

Comment: No I understand your point, I just disagree. I believe it's so useful that I always recommend its use in any app that needs data/time APIs. [There's also a lightweight version of the library targeted at Android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android), but to each their own.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply split the String by `.` and use the second element?
Like:

```
long millis = Long.parseLong(dateStr.split(".")[1]);
```

Where `dateStr` is a `String` of form `HH:mm:ss.SSS`.

It is much better solution than using a 3rd party library for simple task.