# Difference between two dates and TimeZone

Tags: java, android

```
String s1 = "00:00:00.221";
String s2 = "00:00:44.221";

Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar c3 = Calendar.getInstance();

SimpleDateFormat myformat= new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");

c1.setTime(myformat.parse(s1));
c2.setTime(myformat.parse(s2));

long mills= c2.getTimeInMillis() - c1.getTimeInMillis();

c3.setTimeInMillis(mills);

String g1 = String.valueOf(c3.get(Calendar.HOUR));
String g2 = String.valueOf(c3.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
String g3 = String.valueOf(c3.get(Calendar.SECOND));
String g4 = String.valueOf(c3.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
String res = g1 + ":" + g2 + ":" + g3 + "."+g4;
```

i expect **res = "00:00:44.000"**
but **res = "03:00:44.000"**

Why **g1** is **3** hour?

I think its TimeZone. But why? How to do it right?

Comment: What do you mean by "right" here? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but "00:00:00.221" doesn't look like something that should be formatted as a `Date` to start with. Perhaps you should parse it as a `Duration` instead? That sounds more likely to be useful.

Comment: Note that calling `Calendar.setTimeInMillis` to be the *difference* between two millisecond values is almost *always* going to be inappropriate. If you could tell us more about your aim here, it would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet - OMG, can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you.

Comment: @Serjaru - Yes, it's your timezone. The problem is that when you use `setTimeInMillis` with the value you're using, you're setting it from The Epoch (Jan 1st 1970 at midnight GMT). Since your timezone is (apparently) 3 hours ahead of GMT, you get 3 instead of 0 for hours. Although you *can* this this by using calendars set to GMT (`Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))`), I think you're probably better off modifying your approach, building on the answers to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282417/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       try {
        String s1 = "00:00:00.221";
        String s2 = "00:00:44.221";
        SimpleDateFormat myformat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = myformat.parse(s1);
        Date date1 = myformat.parse(s2);

        long value = date1.getTime() - date.getTime();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        calendar.setTime(new Date(value));
        String g1 = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
        String g2 = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        String g3 = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        String g4 = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
        String res = g1 + ":" + g2 + ":" + g3 + "." + g4;
        Toast.makeText(this, res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can set timezone to UTC format,